# How I can send object to a view in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How I can send object to a view, currently I have something like that:

```
Route::get('/search', 'sampleController@search')->name('search');
```

So, I have this object `{Page_title:$pageName,error:$errorMesssage}` and I want to pass it to `/search` route.

Also, how I can retrieve the object values in the view side.

Comment: send from in your search method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to know how to send **data** from controller to `view`, if so

```
   Public function search(){
       $pageName = 'your page name';
       $error = 'something went wrong';

       return view('yourview')->with([
               'page_title'=> $pageName,
               'error'=> $errorMesssage
           ]);
   }
```

Now you can access those variable in your blade file as

```
{{$page_title}}

{{$error}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth mentioning that as of Laravel 5, passing data to the view is now done like this :

```
return view('blog')->with('pageName',  'Page Name')->with('errorMesssage', 'Error Message');
```

Or,

```
return view("blog", ["pageName"=> "Page Name", "errorMessage" => "Error Message" ]);
```

In your  view :

```
Page : {{ $pageName ??  null }} // if variable not assigned then you don't get any error
Message : {{ $errorMessage ?? null }} // if variable not assigned then you don't get any error
```